# How do I prevent JMeter from exiting upon successful execution of the test?

Tags: jmeter

I am running JMeter version 3.3 in non-GUI mode and I do not want the process to exit upon successful execution of the test.

I have tried running following command:

```
$ ./bin/jmeter -n -t scenarios/WebTestPlan.jmx -LDEBUG -Jjmeterengine.force.system.exit=false
```

But it doesn't do the trick. How do I achieve desired behavior?

Comment: Why do you want that ?

Comment: It is related to the fact that I am deploying my jmeter as a worker app to Heroku. Once execution of the test is over, Heroku will make an attempt to re-launch it for high availability guarantees. I do not want that process to get re-launched and there is no way to tweak that behavior on Heroku side, so I started looking at JMeter options.

Comment: Would a duration do the trick for you ? Are you sure it's not customizable on Heroku ? looks strange

Comment: I am sure about it. But I think I can launch my JMeter via shell script in which I could throw `sleep infinity` and that might do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If basing your approach on time is acceptable and you don't need JMeter report to be generated on Heroku, add a tearDown Thread Group that contains an infinite sleep using Timer.

If you need report, then do a sleep in a shell